# How to upload File from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my application am allowing the user to upload file from the URL

code to upload File URL:

```
function loadURL(box) {
       var box = dhtmlx.modalbox({
           title: "Load URL",
           text: "<div id='form_in_box'><div>Enter the URL of PDF file <hr/><input type='text' name='files' id='files' style='width: 400px; height: 27px;'></label><br></div><div><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='submit' value='Load URL' style='width: 86px' onclick='load_file(this)'></span><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='close_file(this)' style='width:80px;'></span></label></div></div>",
           width: "300px"
       })
   }



function load_file(box) {
   var file = document.getElementById('files');
   if (file == "") {
       alert("Enter File URL");
       return false;
   }
   file = file.value;
  var filename = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);
   $.post("/FileUpload/UploadURL",
                   { file: '' + file + ''
                   });
```

}

Controller code

```
public ActionResult UploadURL(string file)
    {
        string files = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string myStringWebResource = "";
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        myStringWebResource = file;
        string path = Server.MapPath(_fileUploadPath + files);
        myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, path);
        string extFile = Server.MapPath(_fileUploadPath + files);
        return View();
    }
```

Files are gettinig downloaded successfully. Now I want to upload the same file How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML file upload control is for **uploading** from client's computer only. What you have to do is to **download** file from another server and save it at yours. [This thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1686462.aspx/1) should help.

Comment: I did as u said. File is getting downloaded successfully. now I want to upload that file and want to show it in tabular form . how can i do so?

Comment: Modified code
public ActionResult UploadURL(string file)
        {
            string files = Path.GetFileName(file);
            string myStringWebResource = "";
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            myStringWebResource = file;
            string path = Server.MapPath(_fileUploadPath + files);
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, path);
            string extFile = Server.MapPath(_fileUploadPath + files);

Comment: @pihu Please add this code to your question, because it's hard to read code from comment.

Comment: @pihu With this code you're downloading file from another server to your own server, so you should already have a file in your server's file system, so what do you want to upload?

Comment: Yes sorry.. I din't observe that its getting uploaded to the server